# VBA for find, match and move data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find an automated solution for the following daily task.
I have a master workbook with 13 sheets.

Names are Jan-Dec (all 12 months) and Data.

Every sheet has 2 sets of 3 columns: Item Code (A1), Year (B1), Price (C1) and Item Code (E1), Year (F1), Price (G1).

Every day I have over 1000 new entries in "Data" sheet and then have to find matching item code (in Column A) in other 12 sheets, columns A-C, cut and move new matching data to E-G and highlight the new entries.

I tried the following vba code:

```
Sub TestNewCode()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim varMainRange As Range
Dim varSubRange As Range
Set varMainRange = Range(Worksheets("Jul").Range("A2:C65536"), _
Worksheets("Jul").Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
For Each MainCell In varMainRange
    Set varSubRange = Range(Worksheets("Data").Range("A2"), _
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    For Each SubCell In varSubRange
        If MainCell.Value = SubCell.Value Then
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:C2").Copy _
    Worksheets("Jul").Range("E2:G2")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next SubCell
Next MainCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

As you can see this code can move only one cell.
I'll appreciate if someone can show a solution to this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't fully test this code, in part because I doubt that you really want to post the data to any of the 12 monthly sheets. Instead, I suspect that the data must be posted to one particular of the monthly sheets. However, that isn't what you said, and therefore my code will look in all sheets and stop looking after it finds a match. This is something you may find easy to adjust. Otherwise I can help you do it.

However, what this code needs now is thorough testing. :-)

```
Sub TestNewCode()
    ' 16 Sep 2017

    Const Tabs As String = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"

    Dim WsData As Worksheet
    Dim Ws As Worksheet                             ' any of the monthly sheets
    Dim WsName() As String
    Dim Rend As Long, Rl As Long                    ' last row in WsData / Ws
    Dim R As Long, Rm As Long                       ' row counter WsData / Ws
    Dim Entry As Variant                            ' one Data entry

    Set WsData = Worksheets("Data")
    WsName = Split(Tabs, " ")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WsData
        Rend = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 2 To Rend
            Entry = .Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, 3)).Value     ' A:C
            Rm = FindMatch(Entry, Ws, WsName)
            If Rm Then                              ' rm = 0 if not found
                With Ws.Cells(Rm, 5).Resize(1, UBound(Entry, 2))
                    .Value = Entry
                    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End With
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function FindMatch(Entry As Variant, _
                           Ws As Worksheet, _
                           WsName() As String) As Long
    ' return zero if no match was found

    Dim Rng As Range                        ' search range
    Dim Fnd As Range
    Dim Rl As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(WsName)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Ws = Worksheets(WsName(i))
        If Err Then
            MsgBox "Worksheet " & WsName(i) & " doesn 't exist.", _
                   vbInformation, "Missing worksheet"
        Else
            With Ws
                Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rl, 3))
                Set Fnd = Rng.Find(What:=Entry(1, 1), _
                      After:=Rng.Cells(Rng.Cells.Count), _
                      LookIn:=xlValues, _
                      Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                      MatchCase:=False, _
                      MatchByte:=False)
                If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
                    FindMatch = Fnd.Row
                    Exit For
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    If Fnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Code " & Entry(1, 1) & " wasn't found.", _
               vbInformation, "Missing Code"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Variatus, your code worked perfectly! Thanks for your reply and sharing your knowledge!

Is it possible to add few more functions to the code?
1- If Cell A is a match, go to Cell B and look for a match, if Cell B also a match, move data (cut-paste) from "Data" sheet 
2- If find same data in different sheets (exact match with column A and B), don't move data, but highlight cells in "Data" sheet

Comment: I'm glad it worked. It would surely be possible to do the things you say, but not within the scope of this thread. The question has been asked and answered, and that is what counts for this forum. I suggest you try to make the modifications yourself first and then, if you should really fail, come back with another question.